# Describe array with implicitely named elements in OpenAPI/Swagger specification

Tags: swagger, openapi

Say my API, for performance reasons, sends what semantically should be a record, as an array in JSON.
So we have arrays with fixed number of items, each with their own name and type:

`/candles/{id}`

```
[
  [
    "BTC/USD",              // Pair
    1529798400000,          // Open time
    0.00014272,             // Open price
    0.00014298,             // High price
    0.00014249,             // Low price
    0.00014249,             // Close price
    54247.00000000,         // Volume
    1529799299999,          // Close time
    {                       // Taker volume
      base: 14870.00000000,   // buy base asset volume
      quote: 2.12351540       // buy quote asset volume
    },
    7.73785568,             // Quote asset volume
  ],
  ...
]
```

How would one describe this in an [OpenAPI/Swagger Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) configuration file ? (for consumption by [swagger-ui](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/))

Comment: In terms of OpenAPI it's just an array of arrays of numbers. What did you try so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Helen Ok I edited my question to provide a more distinctive example with different types. Tell me if you get my problem. Basically, can one describe the elements of an array individually ?

Comment: If it's a mixed-type array, see the ^^ linked question. Note that you can only define the element types (string, number, object), but you cannot define their order or individual descriptions for 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. items.

Comment: Okay thanks. So I take it that my API can't be described  with Openapi. Feel free to post an answer just saying that so I can accept it!