# Does Swagger(OpenAPI) 2.0 support tuple type?

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

I am a noobie. I am trying to document an API with swagger 2.0 yaml and its response is like this

[image]

As you can see, the type of 'type' is string, 'id' is integer, 'name' is string. But what type is 'geography'? I was going to put 'object' type but it seems object type is simply a json object.

According to the website, OpenAPI only supports these types
string (this includes dates and files)
number
integer
boolean
array
object

Comment: `geography` is a string, not a tuple. A tuple would look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51179677/113116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `geography` is a string.

```yaml
geography:
  type: string
```